# How to produce mermaid flowcharts that contain a title and description per node

Tags: mermaid

I am working on ROS robots. I wanted to document the launchfiles using mermaid. Some things in these xml files would best fit into the same node like:

- Name
- Type
- Description
- ...

Adding them as separate nodes would make th diagrams really unreadable, so how would I generate nodes that contain these information ncely formatted?

Comment: can you paste a similar diagram? or a sketch version?